# loss increase when updating "State"

Tags: tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

I would like to update state, So here is what i wrote:

```
def create_keras_model():
...
   return model
iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(..)
```

My problem is loss increase contrary to the accuracy which makes a small decrease:

```
round  1, metrics=OrderedDict([('categorical_accuracy', 0.4675926), ('loss', 8.581259)])
round  2, metrics=OrderedDict([('categorical_accuracy', 0.65625), ('loss', 5.4126678)])
round  3, metrics=OrderedDict([('categorical_accuracy', 0.6018519), ('loss', 6.37924)])
round  4, metrics=OrderedDict([('categorical_accuracy', 0.587963), ('loss', 6.5979366)])
round  5, metrics=OrderedDict([('categorical_accuracy', 0.6400463), ('loss', 5.7463913)])
round  6, metrics=OrderedDict([('categorical_accuracy', 0.6909722), ('loss', 4.872179)])
round  7, metrics=OrderedDict([('categorical_accuracy', 0.6469907), ('loss', 5.6218925)])
round  8, metrics=OrderedDict([('categorical_accuracy', 0.7037037), ('loss', 4.723536)])
round  9, metrics=OrderedDict([('categorical_accuracy', 0.7002315), ('loss', 4.774122)])
round 10, metrics=OrderedDict([('categorical_accuracy', 0.7060185), ('loss', 4.6346316)])
round 11, metrics=OrderedDict([('categorical_accuracy', 0.6724537), ('loss', 5.213738)])
round 12, metrics=OrderedDict([('categorical_accuracy', 0.6608796), ('loss', 5.450448)])
```

Is there another solution to solve this problem ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are these the *training* metrics or *test* metrics? Its important to note that training metrics have "weird" behavior in Federated Learning; see [MSE error different during training and evaluation in tensorflow federated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59193069/mse-error-different-during-training-and-evaluation-in-tensorflow-federated).

If `create_keras_model` is loading pretrained weights that already accurately learned the  distribution of the data, this might be some fine-tuning step. However if these are training metrics, they may not be telling the whole story (as above). I would also recommend running for more rounds, 10 rounds is generally not enough in Federated Learning.

For more about interpreting machine learning metrics in general, see [How to interpret increase in both loss and accuracy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40910857/how-to-interpret-increase-in-both-loss-and-accuracy).